# How to configure Show Owner Info on Lock Screen on Galaxy S2 / Android 4.0.3?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, lock-screens

I just upgrade my S2 to Android 4.0.3, and I'm trying to configure it to show my info on the lock screen.

I go to Setup-->Security-->Owner info

Then, I type in the info, but I don't find any way to save or submit this info. I can only hit the back button, and then when I go to the lock screen, nothing is displayed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no submit button. Just hit the back button and lock your phone to see the result.

Comment: Sorry, I just missed the scrolling text on the lock screen for some reason. I was sure I'll see it larger, damn my lying eyes :)

Comment: Glad you noticed it now :D

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem initially. Nothing happens after setting up the owner's info.

Then I unplugged my USB cable and voilà, it appears under the clock!

Hope this helps... (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the check box is selected above the text entry field where you type in your message.